# Performance getting rows with max column

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, performance, query-performance

I have an historic table called 'historic', with three columns: object_id, day, value.
For historical reason, day(date) is an integer number (number of day since 01/01/1904)
Example:

```
object_id | day | value
------------------------
1         |  5   | blue
1         |  7   | red
1         |  8   | green
2         |  4   | blue
2         |  11  | green
3         |  6   | blue
```

I want to get all value for a max-date before a specified date:
For example, as of 'day <= 7', I want this result:

```
object_id | day  | value
------------------------ 
1         |  7   | red 
2         |  4   | blue 
3         |  6   | blue
```

I have tried several option:

## Subquery

```
select 
*
from historic H1, 
  (
  select max(day) as date,
  object_id 
  from historic 
  where  
    day <= :my_date
  group by object_id
  ) H2 
where 
  H1.day = H2.day 
  and   
  H1.object_id = H2.object_id  
order by h1.object_id
```

### Execution plan

```
| Id  | Operation               | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                        |     8 |   608 |     7  (29)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                 |                        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT GROUP BY         |                        |     8 |   608 |     7  (29)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN            |                        |     8 |   608 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| HISTORIC_PK            |     4 |   104 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | HISTORIC               |     6 |   300 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   1 - filter("H1"."DAY"=MAX("DAY"))
   3 - access("H1"."OBJECT_ID"="OBJECT_ID")
   4 - filter("DAY"<=7)
```

## Analytic function

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT 
      object_id, 
      value,
      day,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY day DESC) d_rank
    FROM historic where day <= 7
  ) where d_rank = 1
```

### Execution plan

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                     |     4 |   204 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |                     |     4 |   204 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|                     |     4 |   152 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | HISTORIC            |     4 |   152 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   1 - filter("D_RANK"=1)
   2 - filter(RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY "OBJECT_ID" ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("DAY") 
              DESC )<=1)
   3 - filter("DAY"<=7)
```

But performance is poor. What is the fastest way to get this result ?
(Real table has 100.000.000 rows)

Comment: What indexes do you have on that table? What's the explain plan of those queries?

Comment: I have an index on "object_id, day". 
For the exec plan, I'll create the test case and update my question asap.